# Resources$NotFoundException for AppCompat in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter, android-theme, android-appcompat

I have the following spinner in my android application:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spnYear"
         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1" />
```

When I define the following adapter for it everything is ok:

```
adapterYears = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spnYear.setAdapter(adapterYears);
```

but when I define the following adapter:

```
adapterYears = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Light_DropDownItem_Spinner);
spnYear.setAdapter(adapterYears);
```

I get run-time error:

```
12-03 15:41:01.789: E/AndroidRuntime(922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 15:41:01.789: E/AndroidRuntime(922): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0057
12-03 15:41:01.789: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1010)
12-03 15:41:01.789: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2088)
12-03 15:41:01.789: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:849)
```

I noticed that the resources in the `appcompat_v7` project is not added to my apk file.

When I use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and I hold the Ctrl Button and put the mouse over the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` I have the following menu:

[image]

But when I use `R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Light_DropDownItem_Spinner` And hold the Ctrl button I do not have any menu for opening the xml file.

I think the problem is about adding the library to my project but I could not find the problem.

I have followed the link https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library but the problem is not solved.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Light_DropDownItem_Spinner* is not a layout, it needs the ID for a layout file like the first you used or like *support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml* available in AppCompat.